# How to extract tag names from an XSD?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I need to write in Java. Is there any sample code available in this regard?

Comment: i tried executing the above mentioned code, it displays only the starting tag and nothing more

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache XmlSchema library (http://ws.apache.org/commons/xmlschema14).

The idea is to create the instance of XmlSchema class that represents your schema:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XmlSchemaCollection schemaCol = new XmlSchemaCollection();
XmlSchema schema = schemaCol.read(new StreamSource(is), null);
```

and use it to obtain information about elements and types specified by your schema. You could for instance enlist all element names:

```
XmlSchemaObjectTable objTable = schema.getElements();
Iterator elementNames = objTable.getNames();
```